# toggle an html section on laravel 4.2 when using return Redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my view i have this section where a user can add a new record to the database but the laravel form is inside a section where it is hidden by default here is my code in my view

```
<section id="anCity" style="display:none">
{{ Form::open(array('url'=> 'addCty')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('ncty', 'City Name: ') }} <span style="color:red"><i>{{ $errors->first('ncty', ':message') }}</i></span>
      {{ Form::text('ncty', Input::old('ncty'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Insert City Name')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Add new City', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
</section>
```

And inside my controller here is my code

```
$rules = array(
    'ncty' => 'required|max:100|alpha_num'
);  

$messages = array(
    'ncty.required' => 'Please enter City Name.',
    'ncty.max'      => 'City Name can only have a maximum of 100 characters',
    'ncty.alpha_num' => 'City Name can only contain alphanumeric characters'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) 
{
    return Redirect::to('lookup_board')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
} 
else
{
    //insert new record
}
```

Is there a way to toggle the section on my view on the controller?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like:

```
<span class="@if($errors and $errors->has('ncty')) has-error @endif">{{ $errors->first('ncty') }}
```

I suppose you are using Twitter Bootstrap so it already has a class has-error for errors that you can use.

Comment: is there a way to clear the error? cause i also have a section named  `anEthnicity` so when i have errors there the section of "anCity" is also showing up

Answer (score 1):

Replace your opening `section` tag with the following:

```html
<section id="anCity"{{ ($errors->any() ? '' : ' style="display:none"') }}>
```

Comment: is there a way to clear the error? cause i also have a section named  `anEthnicity` so when i have errors there the section of "anCity" is also showing up